# How the IP adressess are connected in Azure vnet to vnet connection

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, subnet, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I have just started working on Azure Cloud Services and was trying to establish v-net to v-net Connection within the same subscription and a different location.

```
Vnet name = vnetOne   
Address space = 10.1.0.0/16  
Resource Group = RG  
Location = Australia East  
Subnet name = SubnetOne  
Address range = 10.1.0.0/24  
GatewaySubnet = 10.1.1.0/24  
Virtual network gateway name = VnetOneGateway  
Gateway type = VPN  
VPN type = Route-based  
SKU = vpnGw1    
Public IPAddress=13.75.198.231  
VnetOneGateway=13.75.192.172(13.75.198.231)  
Connection(VnetOneGatewayToVnetTwoGateway)=52.232.102.16

Vnet name = VnetTwo  
Address space = 10.6.0.0/16  
Resource Group = RG  
Location = EuropeWest  
Subnet name = SubnetTWo  
Address range = 10.6.0.0/24  
GatewaySubnet = 10.6.1.0/24  
Virtual network gateway name = VnetTwoGateway  
Gateway type = VPN  
VPN type = Route-based   
SKU = VpnGw1 
Public IP Address=104.40.194.26  
VMTwo: 51.145.142.190  
VMTWo=13.75.193.47 and 10.1.0.4  
VnetTwoGateway=52.232.102.16(40.115.46.34)  
Connection (VnetTwoGatewayToVnetOneGateway) =13.75.192.172
```

Question 1.  I created vnet's with defined Address spaces and then created subnet.Inside subnet I have created VM's which has two ip's one is from taken Subnet Address space and other ---is it assigned randomly?

Question 2.  What is difference between GatewaySubnet and VirtualNetwork Gateway.Means their use.I have seen lot of videos but no one has explained the logical aspect of it.A diagramtic representation will help a lot to understand this.I have only understanding that Virtual Network gateway creates tunnel for interaction between the vnet's using shared key,then what's the role of gateway Subnet?

Question 3.  We have to create the public IP Address and we map it with Virtual Network Gateway.Once the Virtual Network Gateway is created there is IP Address assigned to these gateways
VnetOneGateway=13.75.192.172(13.75.198.231)
VnetTwoGateway=52.232.102.16(40.115.46.34)

which is different from Mapped Public IP Address
Public IPAddress=13.75.198.231(Created for mapping Virtual Network Gateway)
Public IP Address=104.40.194.26.Not able to understand the logic in this scenario.What does the Virtual Network IP Address does and what does the Public Address IP does which is mapped to Virtual Network Gateway?

Question 4.  Can I get the diagrammatic representation of all the IP's interacting with each other.May be I am missing something thats why I am not able to get the logical connection in this.

Any shared link will also be a great help.
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see what you want is to get a connection between vnets. So I suggest the Vnet Peering, it's just a simple way to set up.

Question 1: If you have a VM with two IPs, all the IPs will be assigned be the subnet in order, for example, the one is 10.0.0.4 and the other is 10.0.0.5. You can get more details about [Virtual Network Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) here.

Question 2: IPs in GatewaySubnet is used to transmit the flow from one network to another as Network Routing does. And the Virtual Network Gateway is a tool that used to create the VPN, also as you say:

> Virtual Network gateway creates a tunnel for interaction between the
>   vnets using a shared key.

Question 3: All the Public IPs are used to connect our logic network to the Internet no matter what they are mapped. The Virtual Network IP Addresses are assigned to the devices, let them have an address in Vnet. And the Public Address IP which is mapped to Virtual Network Gateway just makes the Virtual Network Gateway can connect the Internet.
You can get more details about [Public IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses) here.

Question 4: This question is too difficult to list particularly, you can get what you want from the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/networking-overview).

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering all the questions.Will go through the links shared by you!!

Comment: I'm glad the answer is helpful to you:-)